# Using Dynamic Variable Names to Call Static Variable in PHP

Tags: php, hacklang

I am trying to implement a logging library which would fetch the current debug level from the environment the application runs in:

```
23    $level = $_SERVER['DEBUG_LEVEL'];
24    $handler = new StreamHandler('/var/log/php/php.log', Logger::${$level});
```

When I do this, the code fails with the error:

```
A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore,followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores at line 24.
```

How would I use a specific `Logger::` level in this way?

**UPDATE:**

I have tried having `$level = "INFO"` and changing `${$level}` to `$$level`. None of these changes helped.

However, replacing the line 24 with `$handler = new StreamHandler('/var/log/php/php.log', Logger::INFO);` and the code compiles and runs as expected.

The variable itself is declared [here](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/e5900c38147d13f0aa9072aaff7ff0f8dbb253f3/src/Monolog/Logger.php#L97)

`PHP Version => 5.6.99-hhvm`

Comment: I would assume that error means `$level` contains a number or other invalid character? If your `$level` contains what would be a valid PHP variable name, you may need a to remove the `{}` so you get `Logger::$$level`.

Comment: This works just fine, so I'd assume $level is invalid like Mr Glass said.  https://3v4l.org/6Fo5o  I usually represent variable variables as `$$level` though.

Comment: As @MrGlass points out, `$level` probably contains an invalid character. Keep in mind that this error will also be thrown for an invalid class property name, variable may be a bit confusing in this context.

Comment: @MrGlass even if I change the variable to be $level = "INFO", the error still remains. Also tried using $$level instead. Same result.

Comment: how you declare your static class var - can you please add the code?

Comment: @Reflective I think it is declared here: https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/e5900c38147d13f0aa9072aaff7ff0f8dbb253f3/src/Monolog/Logger.php#L97

Comment: the only related static var I see is `protected static $levels` so if you want to get this var write exactly `Logger::$levels` which will return the value of this var

Comment: @Reflective pardon, I looked at the wrong line. I guess the interface implements ```INFO``` as a constant here: https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/e5900c38147d13f0aa9072aaff7ff0f8dbb253f3/src/Monolog/Logger.php#L40
So I, in fact want to get to that constant somehow. If I do $levels it will give me the whole array which is not the intention.

Comment: ok, now I see what you want to achieve. I'm not sure and not tried but may be `Logger::constant($level)` may help. Of course you can always do the following `$logger_levels = Logger::$levels; $reversed_logger_levels = array_flip($logger_levels);  $l = $reversed_logger_levels[$level];`

Comment: @Reflective. Ok, the 2nd option looks pretty ugly, but you are right, there is a ```constant()``` function which does what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer was to use a function for a constant lookup:

`$handler = new StreamHandler('/var/log/php/php.log', constant("Monolog\Logger::" . $level));`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Logger {
  const MY = 1;
}

$lookingfor = 'MY';

// approach 1
$value1 = (new ReflectionClass('Logger'))->getConstants()[$lookingfor];
// approach 2
$value2 = constant("Logger::" . $lookingfor);

echo "$value1|$value2";
?>
```

Result: "1|1"

Comment: :shrug: definitely prefer the 2nd option for the reasons of being a language built in, having more than 0 documentation and simplicity. I think most people would prefer to avoid a reflection wherever possible. So while containing variable is 1:1, the code functionally and structurally is not equivalent.

Comment: Yep, but it's difficult to avoid errors on missing constants.

Comment: that's why I'll be wrapping it into an exception handler.